# IEx truncated Error stackstrace despite of config

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

My config `~/.iex.exs` is :

```
IEx.configure(inspect: [limit: :infinity, printable_limit: :infinity, pretty: true , safe: false] )
```

In IEx, strings, lists are not truncated, but despite the configuration ,I have some errors troncated like :

```
19:35:15.338 [error] #PID<0.404.0> running HTTP (cowboy_protocol) terminated
Server: localhost:4201 (http)
Request: GET /api?elemen_id%5B%5D=FOO_1&elemen_id%5B%5D=FOO_2&*********************************** (truncated)
```

If someone have a good idea !

Thanks !

Comment: You probably need to configure the `logger` application https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.html#module-runtime-configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`inspect:`](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html#configure/1-inspect) option of [`IEx.configure/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html#configure/1) does indeed configure `IEx`

> A keyword list containing inspect options used by the shell when printing results of expression evaluation. Default to pretty formatting with a limit of 50 entries.

It does affect the default options of [`Inspect`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Inspect.html) protocol implementation. Errors come as binaries from what formatted this error *already truncated*. The message comes from `cowboy` which apparently uses [`error_logger`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/error_logger.html) [by default](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/blob/473e3fb82bd56a984dcf8936a51e3fd8affcb8f4/src/cowboy.erl#L86-L90). So, the message might be initially truncated by `error_logger` or, as specified in comments by @m3characters by `Logger` application.

The easiest approach I’d suggest is to config `cowboy` to use `Logger` application and then to [config `Logger`](https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.html#module-runtime-configuration) to not truncate messages by default (use `:infinity` as limit.) Maybe the latter step only would suffice.